# ASP.Net 403 error when adding new razor .cshtml file type

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis, razor

I am working in an environment in which are views are requested via a JQuery viewLoader GET request. I'm trying to port all .html to Razor (.cshtml) and I consistently get 403 errors from the client side when I change the extension on the src property to .cshtml. Note I am doing this because if I keep the request as .html I get a 404 (I thought the cshtml would serve itself as html?) :

```
var cartContainerScript = <script id='CartContainerTemplate' type='text/html' src='./Views/Home/Carts/ED.cshtml' ></script>

$("body").append(cartContainerScript);
cartTemplate = $("script[id=" + 'CartContainerTemplate' + "]");

   cartContainer.viewloader({
        logLevel: "debug",
        scripts: cartTemplate,
        success: function (resolution) {
               //Do good stuff
        },
        error: function (failedResolution) {
            // 403 occurs @ jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2 -> GET http://application.company.com/Views/Home/Carts/ED.cshtml 403 (Forbidden)
        }
    });
```

I tried adding a *.cshtml entry in the last line of the below HTTP routing in my Views/Web.config file with no luck:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="*.aspx;*.ascx" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
  <remove path="*.view.html" verb="*"  />
  <remove path="Carts\*.html" verb="*"  />
  <remove path="Carts\*.cshtml" verb="*"  />
</httpHandlers>
```

Is there anyway to serve up the Razor files as html after compilation? Perhaps I am missing something in my web.config?

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have to change `<modules>` to 
`<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">`

```
<system.webServer>
    ...
    <modules> => <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    ...
</system.webServer>
```

This Web.config is at the root directory, not the one in *Views* directory.

But still, without IIS settings and Web.Config details, it's hard to tell what would cause this issue.